# extract multiple occurrences with same xpath from xml in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have an xml like this:

```
<root>
  <parentTag>
    <child1>p1c1</child1>
    <child2>p1c2</child2>
    <child3>p1c3</child3>
  </parentTag>      
  <parentTag>
    <child1>p2c1</child1>
    <child2>p2c2</child2>
    <child3>p2c3</child3>
  </parentTag>
  <parentTag>
    <child1>p3c1</child1>
    <child2>p3c2</child2>
    <child3>p3c3</child3>
  </parentTag>
</root>
```

I want to write a query that returns the columns Child1, Child2 and Child3 with all the values in the tags for child1, child2 and child3.

```
Child1  Child2  Child2
p1c1    p1c2    p1c3
p2c1    p2c2    p2c3
p3c1    p3c2    p3c3
```

Also, there are multiple records in the table with the same xml, I am trying to get all the data within the child1,child2 and child3 records from all the records. Please help.

Comment: The tag `sql` is not enough... Please always tag with the actual RDBMS (vendor and version)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not tag your RDBMS, this is **SQL-Server-syntax**. But - as you used the `XPath`-tag too, other DBMS will handle this quite similar.

First use a function like `.nodes()` to get the `<parentTag>`-nodes row-wise. Then use the `XQuery`-expression `[local-name()="child1"]` to read the child element with the given name.

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'<root>
  <parentTag>
    <child1>p1c1</child1>
    <child2>p1c2</child2>
    <child3>p1c3</child3>
  </parentTag>      
  <parentTag>
    <child1>p2c1</child1>
    <child2>p2c2</child2>
    <child3>p2c3</child3>
  </parentTag>
  <parentTag>
    <child1>p3c1</child1>
    <child2>p3c2</child2>
    <child3>p3c3</child3>
  </parentTag>
</root>';

SELECT nd.value('(*[local-name()="child1"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Child1
      ,nd.value('(*[local-name()="child2"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Child2
      ,nd.value('(*[local-name()="child3"])[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Child3
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/parentTag') AS A(nd)
```

UPDATE: If the XML is living within a table...

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM YourTable
 OUTER APPLY YourTable.TheXMLColumn.nodes( ...
```

The rest is the same as above.

Comment: okay, how to i refer to the xml from the table? the column name for XMLTYPEis xml_info